# Linux- Trying to install fig2dev

Tags: linux, installation

I installed xfig and am now trying to install fig2dev in order to export figures from it into a pdf format. I downloaded the zip file from the source and unzipped it, but I keep getting an error when running the install command listed in the install file. Can anyone tell me where the bottom code is going wrong? The operating system is linux mint if that helps. I was able to download xfig using the apt-get install command, but I cannot seem to get fig2dev using that command.

```
robert@robert-Aspire-E5-575G ~/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a $ sudo ./configure CFLAGS='-O2 -Wno-parentheses'; make -j install-strip
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for library containing cos... -lm
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for library containing iconv... none required
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for library containing png_read_info... no
checking for png in /opt/local/lib /sw/lib... no
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for library containing XpmReadFileToXpmImage... -lXpm
checking X11/xpm.h usability... yes
checking X11/xpm.h presence... yes
checking for X11/xpm.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for getpwuid... yes
checking for _setmode... no
checking for isascii... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating man/fig2dev.1
config.status: creating fig2dev/Makefile
config.status: creating fig2dev/dev/Makefile
config.status: creating fig2dev/bitmaps/Makefile
config.status: creating fig2dev/i18n/Makefile
config.status: creating fig2dev/tests/Makefile
config.status: creating fig2dev/tests/atlocal
config.status: creating transfig/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing fig2dev/tests/atconfig commands
configure: Results:
  preprocessor      CPP:        gcc -E
  preprocessor flags    CPPFLAGS:   <empty>
  compiler      CC:     gcc
  compiler flags    CFLAGS:     -O2 -Wno-parentheses
  linker flags      LDFLAGS:    <empty>
  libraries     LIBS:       -lXpm -lm 
  install location  prefix:     /usr/local

Files will be installed under /usr/local.
if test -z ''; then \
  make  INSTALL_PROGRAM="/bin/bash /home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/install-sh -c -s" \
    install_sh_PROGRAM="/bin/bash /home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/install-sh -c -s" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
      install; \
else \
  make  INSTALL_PROGRAM="/bin/bash /home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/install-sh -c -s" \
    install_sh_PROGRAM="/bin/bash /home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/install-sh -c -s" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
    "INSTALL_PROGRAM_ENV=STRIPPROG=''" install; \
fi
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a'
Making install in fig2dev
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev'
Making install in dev
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/dev'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/dev'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/dev'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/dev'
Making install in bitmaps
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/bitmaps'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/bitmaps'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/fig2dev/bitmaps'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/fig2dev’: Permission denied
Makefile:289: recipe for target 'install-dist_bitmapsDATA' failed
make[4]: *** [install-dist_bitmapsDATA] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/bitmaps'
Makefile:359: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev/bitmaps'
Makefile:560: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a/fig2dev'
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/robert/Downloads/fig2dev-3.2.6a'
Makefile:682: recipe for target 'install-strip' failed
make: *** [install-strip] Error 2
```

Comment: Seems like a bug: `checking for Xpm in /opt/local/lib /sw/lib /opt/X11/lib ... no` detects that you dont have libxpm4 installed but even though libxpm4 is a requirement, configure does not fail. Try to install `libxpm4-dev`, looks like it might be called `libxpm-dev` if you are running something Debian based.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I install libxpm-dev and then tried to run the code again and got a similar problem(at least it looks like it to me). I copied and pasted the new code above from the second run attempt.

Comment: Nope, looks much better :) You are running the install script which tries to copy the binaries to `/usr/local/share/fig2dev` which is not writable for your current user.
You need to run the install step as root (e.g. using sudo).

Comment: I thought I did run it as sudo

Comment: Only the first command, you need to run ` make -j install-strip` as root as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. That worked perfectly! I did not realize that the second command was considered separate than the first. I don't know how to give you credit for answering the question, but whatever you need me to do I can do.